# How to set the Return Type of a Class Member Function as the object of a Private Struct

Tags: c++, class, namespaces, structure

sorry for the long and confusing title, but I couldn't think of a better way to ask this. So, what I have is a class:

```
template <typename T>
class Set
{
    public:
        //random member functions here
    private:
        struct Node{
            T key;
            Node *right;
            Node *left;
            int height;
        };
    public:
        Node* r_add(Node *temp);
};


Node* Set<T>::r_add(Node *temp)
{
    return temp;
}
```

When I try to implement the function r_add, I keep getting the error that the return type of out-of-line definition differs from that in the declaration for the r_add function. I'm not exactly clear on how to declare the return type for when I try to call a private structure in a class member function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for that needs to be:

```
template <typename T>
Set<T>::Node* Set<T>::r_add(Node *temp)
{
    return temp;
}
```

Please note that you *don't have to* use `Set<T>::Node*` for the argument type since the scope `Set<T>` will be used for `Node` at that point.

Another option is to use trailing return type. That will allow you to avoid having to type `Set<T>` any more than is necessary.

```
template <typename T>
auto Set<T>::r_add(Node *temp) -> Node*
{
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: It is also possible to use trailing return type syntax which will avoid repetition of `Set<T>::`

Answer (score 0):

```
template <typename T>
typename Set<T>::Node* Set<T>::r_add(typename Set<T>::Node* temp)
{
    return temp;
}
```

here is my implementation for [map](https://github.com/rsy56640/rsy_little_lib/blob/master/library_for_algorithm/RB_Tree/map/rsy_map.h), and you can find the solution to your problem